# Kendo UI Grid, editable mode not working for local data

Tags: kendo-ui

I am working with the Kendo UI Grid. This is my code:

```
<body>
<div id="myGrid"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var rows =  [
    {name: "name001", id: "001", group: "G1"},
    {name: "name002", id: "002", group: "G1"},
    {name: "name003", id: "003", group: "G2"},
    {name: "name004", id: "004", group: "G2"},
    ];

    var myDataSource =
        new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: rows,
            pageSize: 3,
        });

    myDataSource.read();
    $("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: myDataSource,
        columns: [
            {field:"name", title:"The Name"},
            {field:"id", title:"The Id"},
            {field:"group"},
            {command:["edit", "destroy"]}
            ],
        scrollable: false,
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true,
        groupable: true,
        filterable: true,
        editable: "inline"
    });

});
</Script>
</body>
```

But the edit is not working. Opening this grid in a browser gives me a grid that looks as expected with an Edit and a Delete button. I can delete rows with the Delete button. But clicking Edit changes the row into edit mode (with input fields in cells) but changing a value and pressing the Update button does nothing. The row remains in edit mode and the Update button doesn't switch back to "Edit" as it's supposed to.
Can you tell me what's missing? Do I have to configure my datasource somehow?

Comment: I've checked your code as it is and worked perfectly well not having to add a single line of code I've tested it in Windows IE7 and Mac OS (Firefox, Safari and Chrome). Please check that you are using the latest version of KendoUI. Please, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510765/is-it-possible-to-have-full-crud-functions-in-kendo-grid-with-local-data?rq=1) other question in StackOverflow and go to John Bristowe answer (he works for KendoUI!).

Comment: I don't think that this has actual relevance for your problem but the script closing tag has an uppercase 'S'. I've tried editing your question but since the change is only one character I couldn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you missed to configure your Grid's dataSource to know how to update the records. I assume that you want to edit the records only locally (on the client) - without sending them to the server. To actually close the Grid and apply the changes you can use the save event of the Grid and the refresh method.

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/edamuj/63/edit) with your case.

If you want to save these changes to the server I suggest you to start with the [demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html).

Comment: do you know how to do this for MVC?